# trying to find if a file exists in a given path

Tags: java, filepath

I am fairly new to java and I am trying to find if the file specified in the LINUX path exists.

```
private void validateFilePath(String filePath) {

        File dir = new File(filePath);

        if(dir.exists()){
                System.out.println("File exists in the path " + dir);
                setTARGET_IMG_DIR("filePath");
                return; 
        }else{
            System.out.println("File does not exists in the path: " + dir);
            return;
        }

    }
```

The dir.exists works fine if I give a absolute path from my root like this

```
/Users/yv/Documents/Eclipse-workspace/InputParser/bin/test.txt
```

but if I give a relative path like 
`test.txt` or `/InputParser/bin/test.txt` it says files does not exists.

I am planing on creating a jar of this projects and hence this should work with both relative path(files in the same directory) and absolute path from the root. How can I handle this ?

Is it possible to search for the absolute path of that file from the root and append it to the file name ?

Comment: Try doing `System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());` and see if this is actually what you expect it to be

Comment: Yes for path /InputParser/bin/test.txt i get the same as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse typically runs with the project directory set as the `user.dir`, that is the base directory for execution. So if the absolute path is:

```
/Users/yv/Documents/Eclipse-workspace/InputParser/bin/test.txt
```

Then the relative path will be:

```
bin/test.txt
```

You can double check the working directory by getting the `user.dir` property from Java's system properties. For more information on Java's system properties [check the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: So dir.exists() is enough to determine if the file exists provided the path given by the user is valid ? I don't have to worry about converting the relative to absolute ?

Comment: In my experience, yes, `dir.exists()` should be enough. I think you will only get into trouble with an abstract path if you try to navigate beyond the abstract path's boundaries (like calling 'getParent' when the abstract path did not include a parent directory).

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is because the current directory where your eclipse program runs is not the one where `test.txt`is located. Also note that `/InputParser/bin/test.txt`is an absolute path, while `InputParser/bin/test.txt`, or `./InputParser/bin/test.txt`are relative paths. You can find more details on paths on [wikipedia (look at Unix-like)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)

Now, to find out the directory where eclipse runs your program, you might want to add

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

-in your program, as pointed out by Alex-

EDIT: changed command to get the current directory

Comment: After running dir.getAbsolutePath it seems eclipse is running it in my bin dir. I have test.txt in my bin and I gave test.txt as input. It din't work

Comment: Thanks man I figured it out. Eclipse was using user dir as base dir and I got confused.

Answer (score 1):

Add the project root directory to your classpath and use `Class.getResource()` to check for existence and `Class.getResourceAsStream()` to read the content of the files. This will work the same whether your files are in the file system or in a jar.